# Javascript problem to enter a bootcamp, how to extract a password?

Tags: javascript, extract

In the last few days I've been going around this particular problem that I can't manage to solve.

It goes like this:

> Create a function named extractPassword which takes an array of characters (which includes some trash characters) and returns a string with only valid characters (a - z, A - Z, 0 - 9)

Here's an example:'

```
extractPassword(['a', '-', '~', '1', 'a', '/']); // should return the string 'a1a'
extractPassword(['~', 'A', '7', '/', 'C']); // should return the string 'A7C''
```

My code is

```js
var new1 = [];

function extractPassword(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var y = array[i];
    if (('a' <= y && y <= 'z') || ('A' <= y && y <= 'Z') || ('0' <= y && y <= '9')) {
      new1.push(y);
    }
  }
}

extractPassword(['a', 'T', '~', 'L', '2']);
console.log(new1.join(''));
```

The console Output is correct 'aTL2' but it gives me an error still 'Code is incorrect, your function is not returning the correct value'.

I've tried putting the var new1 inside the function but then it says that the variable is undefined. I don't know what I can do to make this code work. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Your `extractPassword()` function isn't returning the value - it's modifying the `new1` array. I'm assuming you're using an online code teaching site, so it may be detecting the response from the function directly, not the `new1` array.

Comment: It's probably working correctly, but if you run that function multiple times it will cause problems because you're using `new1` as a global variable.  Have it return an array (or better the string you want) instead

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
function extractPassword(array) {
  var new1 = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var y = array[i];
    if (('a' <= y && y <= 'z') || ('A' <= y && y <= 'Z') || ('0' <= y && y <= '9')) {
      new1.push(y);
    }
  }
  return new1;
}

let a = extractPassword(['a', 'T', '~', 'L', '2']);
console.log(a.join(''));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Unfortunately I cannot use the 'const' declaration for this exercise.

Comment: Then just replace it with `var unallowedChars = ['~', '/', '-'];`

Comment: Same goes with filter xp

Comment: No, you don't need to change anything. Just change `const` to `var` that's it. It should work exactly the same.

Comment: yes I undestand, the problem is I cannot use filter aswell. I believe the problem has to do with how Im returning the values and not the 'if' part. If that makes sense (sorry im a newbie).

Comment: Ah sorry, I got the point. Just return your `new1` array in the next line of for loop (not inside the for loop). `return new1;` and that's it.

Comment: I did that and it doesnt do much. I still get the same error :c Yes I tried outside the loop

Comment: Can you try to create your array inside the function. Top of the function, not outside.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. For some reason, after I do that it says undefined var.

Comment: Can you try the answer again, i edited the code.

Comment: Finally it worked! I had to put return new1.join(' ').

Comment: You're welcome. Yet you there are much shorter and performant ways to achieve this than using that code piece. FYI. Since you are not allowed to use a lot of things, I go with your code.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved with regular expressions. The .join method combines all the array elements into a string, and the .replace method searches for all characters that are not a letter or number, and replaces them with "", giving the desired output

```js
function extractPassword(input){
    return input.join('').replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '');
}

console.log(extractPassword(['a', '-', '~', '1', 'a', '/'])); // a1a
console.log(extractPassword(['~', 'A', '7', '/', 'C'])); // A7C
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I cannot use expressions they haven't taught me yet. I know that a pain for yall experienced users but I have to work with the cards they give me :p

Comment: replace for instance is one of them that I haven't learnt

Answer (score -1):

I saw there are a lot of restrictions to what you can use just a tweak to your code that might work for you.
you don't need to use an external variable for this if I understand correctly you only need a method.

```
function extractPassword(array) {
  var password = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var y = array[i];
    if (('a' <= y && y <= 'z') || ('A' <= y && y <= 'Z') || ('0' <= y && y <= '9')) {
      password+= y;
    }
  }
    return password;
}

console.log(extractPassword(['a', 'T', '~', 'L', '2']));
```

Here is another approach without using any variable here I am trying it with recursion, hope this works.

```
function extractPassword(array) {
    if (array.length == 0) {
        return ""
    } else if (array.length == 1) {
         if (('a' <= array[0] && array[0] <= 'z') || ('A' <= array[0] && array[0] <= 'Z') || ('0' <= array[0] && array[0] <= '9')){
             return array [0]
         }else {
             return ""}
    }
    else {
         return extractPassword(array.slice(0,1))+extractPassword(array.slice(1,array.length))
    }
       
  }
console.log(extractPassword(['a', 'T', '~', 'L', '2']));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
Like I've said, If I put the var inside the function it gives me an undefined error. Says 'password is not defined'.

Comment: does it not give any error for y?
is it some online compiler or platform that you are trying?

Comment: It does not. Im using a platform called n01r. I believe the problem as to do with the return value. For instance. I have to use the .join before the console.log somewhere. But If I put it outside the loop on the return value, like this 'return new1.join(' ')' It doesnt do anything and I believe that's where the problem is.

Comment: I have not used .join can you try the code?